# How to place items in the given position in Minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

I would like to place (drop) some items (or "destroyed" blocks) in the given position.
The `fill` command doesn't work here since it places blocks and a user will have to break it to pick up (but the user should be to collect it, see how `collect` command [works](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Commands/collect)). Probably the `loot` command would be ok, but it is not available at Bedrock Edition.

I can use commands only, command blocks shouldn't be used.

What else could I try?

Answer (score 2):

Run the following two commands in order:

```
/fill x y z x y z your_block_here
/setblock x y z x y z air destroy
```

It's just the commands from Bilal Khalid's answer, except typed in the chat. All commands work in both command blocks AND in the chat.

If you want it all in one command, it may not be possible. Sorry.

Comment: Thanks. Will not `execute` help me to do it with one command?

Comment: `/execute`, although different in Bedrock Edition than in Java, will only be able to run one command at a time. Ideally, if you did have access to command blocks, you could set a redstone block next to a command chain that would then run. Perhaps you could try changing your setup a little? The command block is so powerful, and you're missing out on creating amazing builds!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to drop a block in a specific place; get two command blocks, one impulse and the other chain. Write the fill command in the impulse command block, and, in the chain command block, write `fill (location) air 0 destroy`. Be sure to chain the commands correctly like this: [image: Image showing how to chain command blocks]
Image from: [here](https://www.howtogeek.com/226078/the-beginners-guide-to-command-blocks-in-minecraft/)

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks. Sorry, I didn't mention it initially - it should be commands only, no command block should be used.

Comment: Oh sorry. I don't know how to make without command blocks. Sorry.